# Registration form issue

Tags: php

The problem I'm having is that the  tag isn't allowing for any text to be placed within it. The error that it iss displaying now is `text not allowed in element <ul> in this context`. How am I meant to place these items into an un-ordered list without it? The code I have is below:

```
@extends('layouts.default')

@section('content')
<h1>Register </h1>

@if($errors->has())
    <p>The following errors have occurred:</p>

    ***<ul id="form-errors">

        {{ $errors->first('username', '<li>:message</li>') }}
        {{ $errors->first('password', '<li>:message</li>') }} 
        {{ $errors->first('password_confirmation', '<li>:message</li>') }}
        {{ $errors->first('email', '<li>:message</li>') }} 
    </ul>***
@endif

{{ Form:open('register', 'POST') }}

<p>
    {{ Form::label('username', 'Username') }}<br />
    {{ Form::text('username', Input::old('username') }}
</p>

<p>
    {{ Form::label('password', 'Password') }}<br />
    {{ Form::password('password' }}
</p>

<p>
    {{ Form::label('password', 'Confirm Password') }}<br />
    {{ Form::password('password_confirmation' }}
</p>

<p>
    {{ Form::label('email', 'Email Address') }}<br />
    {{ Form::text('email') }}
</p>

<p>{{ Form::submit('Register') }}</p>

{{ Form::close()}}

@stop
```

Comment: What tag are you talking about? Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Sorry, i could have swore i included the tag in the post,  its the <ul> tag the work thats been place in bold between *** *** either side.

Comment: You appear to be using a framework - which one?